# XNA AdGameComponent does not draw

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, components, ads

I have following code.
But AddGameComponent doesn't draw.

```
   protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        base.Initialize();
        var li = new LicenseInformation();
        IsTrial = li.IsTrial();
        if (IsTrial)
        {
            AdGameComponent.Initialize(this, AppID);
            Components.Add(AdGameComponent.Current);
            CreateAd();
        }
    }


   private void CreateAd()
    {
        bannerAd = AdGameComponent.Current.CreateAd(AdUnitID, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), true);
        AdGameComponent.Current.Enabled = true;
    }
```

I have tried to set DrawOrder to 1000, but ads still doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps this should be migrated to [gamedev.SE]. Please don't cross post. Let a mod move it if need be.

Comment: @Drackir There are many posts here about game-development, everyone is free to post here if he wants to imho. ;-)

Comment: @FelixK. Oh, absolutely. I just meant that the OP will probably get better answers on a site dedicated to the topic. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Ads needed geo-location data.

```
this.gcw = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(); 
this.gcw.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(gcw_PositionChanged); 
this.gcw.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(gcw_StatusChanged); 
this.gcw.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call the corresponding Draw and Update methods from the AdGameComponent, see the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh495436(v=MSADS.20).aspx

Comment: You are wronu, I shouldn't call Draw and Update methods manualy. If I have add DrawbleGameComponent to Components container.